# How to Swap the options of two select Boxes

Tags: jquery, html

I have a Two select Boxes as below.

```
    <form name="test">
        <select id="s1" name="select1">
         <option selected>1</option>
         <option>2</option>
         <option>3</option>
        </select>

        <select id="s2" name="select2">
         <option>1</option>
         <option>2</option>
         <option selectd>3</option>
        </select>

<input type="button" value="swap" id="swap">

    </form>
```

"1" is selected in the select box 1 and "3" is selected in the select box 2.

Now by clicking a button those two value should swap. Means "3" in select box 1 and "1" in select box 2.

I have tried some jquery for that. That code is as below.

```
$("#swap").click(function(){
 v1=document.getElementById("s1");
 v2=document.getElementById("s2");
 document.form.select1.value=v2;
 document.form.select2.value=v1;
});
```

But i didnt get the result. Whats wrong i am doing.??

Thanks in advance,

Shoba.

Comment: Actually the options in the two select boxes will be same. And yes i want selected options should be changed

Comment: As you are using jQuery as code medium, it will be neat, better and easier if you can code everything in jQuery itself, You can replace this lengthy `document.getElementById("s1");` with simple `$('#s1')` in jQuery. Here in your code its mixed up with jQuery and javascript. So please consider this as a suggestion for your future coding.

Comment: Ya sure...Thnks for your suggestion :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$('#swap').click(function(){
    var v1 = $('#s1').val(),
        v2 = $('#s2').val();
    $('#s1').val(v2);
    $('#s2').val(v1);
});
```

[Works fine for me.](http://jsfiddle.net/4SfdZ/)

Comment: Its not working when I use with select2 for search in select box. Can you help for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
  <select name="" id="select_one" multiple>
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
  </select>
  <button onclick="swap('select_one','select_two','left_to_right')">--></button>
  <button onclick="swap('select_one','select_two','right_to_left')"><--</button>
  <select name="" id="select_two" multiple>
     <option value="5">1*5</option>
     <option value="6">2*5</option>
     <option value="7">3*5</option>
     <option value="8">4*5</option>
  </select>
  <script>
     var cloneArr = function(arr){
         var result = [];
         for(var item=0; item<arr.length;item++){
             result[item]=arr[item];
         }
         return result;
     }
     
     function swap(select_one,select_two,direction='left_to_right') {
         select_one = document.querySelector('#select_one');
         select_two = document.querySelector('#select_two');            
         if (direction=='left_to_right') {
             var oneOptions = select_one.selectedOptions;
            var arr = cloneArr(oneOptions);
             for(var item=0; item<oneOptions.length;item++){
                 select_one.remove(oneOptions[item].index);
             }
             for(var item=0; item<arr.length;item++){
                 select_two.add(arr[item]);
             }
         }
     
         if (direction=='right_to_left') {
             var twoOptions = select_two.selectedOptions;
            var arr = cloneArr(twoOptions);
             for(var item=0; item<twoOptions.length;item++){
                 select_two.remove(twoOptions[item].index);
             }
             for(var item=0; item<arr.length;item++){
                 select_one.add(arr[item]);
             }
         }
         
     }
  </script>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.